# Series as indexes for DataFrame

Tags: pandas

Is it possible to use a Series as index for a DataFrame of the same length?
An example:

I have a DataFrame "df" and a Series "c"; the length of "c" is the same as the indexes of "df". The following code:

```
df1= DataFrame(df, index=c)
```

returns me a DataFrame with the right indexes but empty columns

Comment: And if you want to keep the original index as an column you can do reset_index() before you set the index with: df1.index=c

Answer (score 3):

If all you want to do is override the index i would use:

```
df1 = df
df1.index = c
```